If there is [[noreturn]], then why there is no [[always_return]]?
If there is [[noreturn]] (C2X, n3301), then why there is no [[always_return]]?
The semantics of [[always_return]] may be the following:

A function declared with an [[always_return]] attribute shall always return to its caller.

The rationale for [[always_return]] is a hint to compiler to perform optimizations.
Example (taken from N3128):
extern void g(int x);
int f(int a, int b)
{
    g(b ? 42 : 43);
    return a / b;
}

A compiler is free to (optimistically) assume that UB doesn't happen.
However, any (hazardous) consequences of UB happen only if UB happens (i.e. present in execution at abstract machine level).
In this example g may terminate the program (i.e. not return). Hence, as I understand, compiler may not fold b ? 42 : 43 to 42, because at abstract machine level a / b may not be executed, hence compiler may not propagate / use an assumption that b is non-zero.
However, if g is declared with [[always_return]], then, as I understand, compiler may fold b ? 42 : 43 to 42, because at abstract machine level a / b is always executed, hence compiler may propagate / use an assumption that b is non-zero.

P.S. The same question goes for [[may_return]].

UPD. In order to fold b ? 42 : 43 to 42 g needs not only to always return, but also to not have observable behavior (OB). This is so, because in C OB is required to happen before UB. Hence, more attributes may be needed: [[observable]], [[noobservable]]. And g may be declared as:
extern [[always_return]] [[noobservable]] void g(int x);


https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/103167

Because nobody submitted a proposal to that effect ... yet!

IMO why not [probably_return] [almost_certainly_return], [no_one_knows_if_it_returns] etc etc

@pmg I thought that while introducing [[noreturn]] WG already thought of [[always_return]], and that may be someone on SO knows why [[always_return]] wasn't accepted.

"P.S. The same question goes for [[may_return]]" - That's literally the default behavior, all functions without annotations may or may not return. What value would such an annotation bring?

@0___________ Indeed, introducing "fuzzy logic like" (i.e. may / may_not / almost_certainly / etc). attributes is perhaps questionable. However, [[always_return]] is the opposite of [[noreturn]] and perhaps may be useful.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Indeed, thanks. The default behavior doesn't need a special attribute.

"in C OB is required to happen before UB" -- hogwash.  If a program exercises UB then its whole behavior is undefined.  UB is not compartmentalized, nor sequenced relative to anything else. "Undefined" means "undefined". No requirements are placed on such behavior. At all.

@JohnBollinger Quote from C2X, n3301 (emphasis added): "In particular, all observable behavior (5.2.2.4) appears as specified in this document when it happens before an
operation with undefined behavior in the execution of the program."

Well that's new, @pmor.  But also, it's from a note attached to the definition of "Undefined Behavior", and therefore non-normative.  I'm inclined, therefore, to think that any compilers that already do perform the optimization that you suppose should be inhibited probably will continue to do so, and UB will continue to be able to time travel.

Also, "OB is required to happen before UB" is a highly misleading way to describe the content of that note. Noting that "happens before" is a defined term in the spec, a better rendition of the note would be "OB that happens before an instance of UB will manifest as described in the spec". Which is still non-normative.  "happens before" is the condition, not the consequence.

@JohnBollinger The definition of UB refers to specific behavior “upon use of…” and not to the whole program. FYI: this note is a result of the work of the UB study group (see n3128, especially the 1st paragraph of "4. The Case for the Concrete Interpretation"). Re: "perform the optimization that you suppose should be inhibited": misunderstanding. I propose to allow fold b ? 42 : 43 to 42 if g has both [[always_return]] and [[noobservable]].

@pmor, no misunderstanding.  You are suggesting that the spec does not allow the folding optimization unless the the implementation can prove that function g() will return, such that a / b will eventually be evaluated.  Else, that optimization must be inhibited.  I'm telling you that any implementations that do perform that optimization are likely to continue to do it, even though it is impossible to be sure whether a / b will in fact be evaluated.  Inasmuch as execution can in practice be interrupted at any time, your logic would preclude any kind of speculative optimization.

And in any case, the issue is moot as far as this SO question is concerned, for, as I already describe in my answer, a C implementation cannot rely on any function always to return, no matter what attributes are attached to it. Factors outside the programmer's control can prevent it.

You haven't described any practical applications for [[always_return]] (even if combined with [[noobservable]]). The code you showed is just a toy example that doesn't resemble anything a programmer would really write. As such, there doesn't seem to be any motivation for [[always_return]].

@JohnBollinger 1) I'm not supposing (in the sense of "assuming") that this optimization should be inhibited. Per my knowledge, this optimization, as you said, must be inhibited. 2) Any C (but not C++) implementations that do perform that optimization are broken (If g terminates the program then there is never a division by zero). 3) Re: "a C implementation cannot rely on any function always to return": why? For e.g. imaxabs the standard says: "The imaxabs function returns the absolute value." Why cannot a C implementation rely on imaxabs always to return?

@BrianBi Re: "any practical applications": potential performance increase and potential reduction of executable code size. Re: "a toy example / programmer would really write": some (C) code is automatically generated (and may be the subject of such optimization). Also, "after preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded" (phase 4) the resulting code may be the subject of such optimization.

(3) As I already described in my answer and somewhat in a previous comment, even a function whose C semantics are always to return might nevertheless occasionally fail to return, as a result of program or system behavior outside its control.  For example, execution of the function may be interrupted by a signal having program termination as a direct or indirect result.  There are other possibilities.

@JohnBollinger Thanks for the example. Does it mean that e.g. execution of the abort function may be interrupted by a signal having a logic to determine the function's (e.g. abort) caller and returning to that caller? (Hence, violating the semantics of [[noreturn]].)

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica So, opinions are divided: some people think that the default behavior is [[may_return]], some people think that the default behavior is [[always_return]].

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Minor correction: should be "default assumption", not "default behavior". The [[always_return]] default assumption seems to be reasonable since in the majority of cases (perhaps even almost always), a C function does return to its caller.

@pmor, abort() is a standard library function.  It is up to the C implementation to ensure that it behaves according to its requirements.  In particular, if ever it returns for any reason, then that reflects a bug in the implementation.  One that I do not expect to be hard to avoid in practice.

@JohnBollinger Major correction: should be "Any C (and C++)" instead of "Any C (but not C++)".

@pmor, I don't see where you're coming up with "opinions are divided".  Certainly no one here seems to be claiming that otherwise-unmarked functions can or should be expected always to return (unless maybe you).  On the other hand, I don't think it's controversial that implementations must presume that unknown, unmarked functions at least may return.

@BrianBi There are heavily loaded workloads where even 1-2% increase in performance is (very) desirable. This increase may (?) come from "manual markup" of the code using attributes (e.g. likely / unlikely in C++, not [yet] in C).

@JohnBollinger It seems that I confused a default expectation / assumption with the general case (i.e. "at least may return"). The [[always_return]] default assumption seems to be reasonable (see my comment above).

Perhaps we have a question of semantics here, @pmor.  It is absolutely unreasonable for an implementation to assume that any function will always return.  There is no way a programmer or C implementation can ensure a return.  However, it is reasonable to assume that an unknown function generally will return.  That assumption may not in fact hold in any given case, but no matter, because it does not present a practical problem to assume that a function may return when in fact it never does.

You haven't described any use cases where a 1-2% increase in performance is likely to be possible based on an assumption that a function always returns. You merely speculate that there might be some use cases involving automatically generated code. Mere speculation is not motivation for a new feature.

@JohnBollinger A simple (relevant) question: in this example both GCC and Clang produce warnings (even if f is static inline). Are these warnings considered OK?

I don't understand the question @pmor.  Of course those diagnostics are ok.  The spec requires diagnostics in certain situations, but it does not in any way forbid implementations from producing additional diagnostics.  Perhaps you're suggesting that the diagnostics are spurrious, because the implementation should, in some sense, be able to see that function f does not, in fact, return, but there are no requirements on the depth, or even existence of any such analysis. In particular, the implementation need not consider any details of the definition of f in its analysis of of f4.

@JohnBollinger Yes, an implementation is permitted to produce additional diagnostics "as long as a valid program is still correctly translated." Yes, I'm suggesting that the diagnostics are spurious. Re: "no requirements / analysis": OK.


If there is [[noreturn]] (C2X, n3301), then why there is no [[always_return]]?

Ultimately, because the committee did not see (sufficient) value in adding such an attribute.  I'm inclined to guess that they did not see value because it wasn't even proposed, but if it was proposed then it was rejected.  Certainly the proposal to add [[noreturn]] did not contemplate an [[always_return]].
And why would it? There is nothing a user function can do to ensure that it will always return.  It is always possible that the program is killed during execution of the function, or its return is prevented via a debugger, or any of a variety of other things outside the control of the function's programmer happens to prevent the function from returning.
And what good would it do? In the absence of any attribute and / or special knowledge of particular functions, the C implementation must presume that function calls will return. But even if an [[always_return]] promise could in fact be kept reliably, the information is not useful to the implementation.  It's like me asserting that the sun will rise tomorrow.  Even supposing that you have absolute faith in me on those grounds, would you do anything different? No, because to any extent that it makes a difference, you were taking that as a working assumption already.
[[noreturn]] is different.  It affords performance enhancements and improved diagnostics relative to unmarked functions that, by design, do not return.
Additionally, the [[noreturn]] attribute is an alternative to the _Noreturn function specifier that has been in C since C11, so it's not really a new feature.  Switching to an attribute instead of a specifier supports harmonization with C++.  There is no function specifier analogous to your hypothetical [[always_return]].

Have a look to my UPD (at the end of the question). A combination of [[always_return]] and [[noobservable]] (perhaps can be merged into a single attribute) will allow C implementation to perform optimizations based on (optimistic) assumption that UB doesn't happen (coupled with knowledge that a function always return and doesn't contain OB), which will potentially lead to performance increase.

Sorry, @pmor, no, I will not consider modifications made to the question after this answer was posted.  And if you think those modifications make a difference, then you should know better than to make them under the circumstances.

Looking at the example, it is clear that a compiler may perform more optimizations with regards to UB if it knows a certain function never exits the program in a defined way, nor loops forever.

Indeed so, @user20574.  That's the point of the _Noreturn function specifier and the new [[noreturn]] attribute.  But the question is about a hypothetical other attribute indicating that a function always returns, without fail.  It's not at all clear to me that a compiler relying on a function always to return would open any doors for additional optimization -- I think not -- but that's moot because it is not possible to ensure that any function will always return, without fail.

@JohnBollinger you have misread my comment. The opposite, a hypothetical always_return, also allows optimization opportunities - the compiler may reorder potential UB before a function call that always returns, since it knows the UB will happen anyway.

Ok, @user20574.  I'm not sure I agree with your claim, but again, it is moot because there can never be a reliable guarantee that a given function will always return.

@JohnBollinger The compiler doesn't have a bug if a program that was going to execute UB does something "wrong" before the point where the UB is written, and then the user pulls the power cord before the program gets to the line where the UB was written. UB is allowed to "time travel". However, if the UB would have never happened at all because it's written to happen after a function call that contains an infinite loop or calls exit/abort/whatever, it's not allowed to time travel to before that call.

I understand the argument, @user20574, but if we accept the interpretation of UB that C23 now seems to promote (non-normatively) in its new note on the definition of UB, then UB's ability to time travel is severely curtailed.  I'm actually doubtful that that interpretation will in fact be widely accepted, the committee's apparent intent notwithstanding, but it undercuts that argument.  Anyway, again, the question is moot.  If the compiler is in fact permitted to make the kind of optimizations you describe, then it does not need an [[always_return]] attribute to justify them.
